# Boot Loader in Linux

Tags: assembly, bootloader

I hve coded the following bootloader program.but there is a problem.

```
;===================================================================
;Following is an incomplete code of a boot-loader with blanks(.....)
;Replace each blank with appropriate word, words or character
;===================================================================

[ORG 0x7C00]

;==============================================================
;MSG2, MSG3 and MSG4 should describe the right order of typical
;boot-loading functionality (i.e. What basially a boot-loader does?)

MSG1 dd '1. Boot Loader starts ', 0
MSG2 dq '2. Initialize Hardware', 0
MSG3 dq '3. Pass an abstraction of Initialize Hardware', 0
MSG4 dq '4. Execute Kernel', 0
MSG5 dq '5. Boot Loader exits ', 0
;==============================================================

;==============================================================
;Printing the messages (MSG1, MSG2, .....)

MOV SI, MSG1
CALL PrintString ;Call print string procedure
MOV SI, MSG1
CALL PrintString ;Call print string procedure
MOV SI, MSG2
CALL PrintString ;Call print string procedure
MOV SI , MSG3
CALL PrintString ;Call print string procedure
MOV SI , MSG4
CALL PrintString ;Call print string procedure
MOV SI, MSG5
CALL PrintString ;Call print string procedure

JMP $ ;infinite loop here
;===============================================================

;===============================================================
PrintCharacter: ;Procedure to print character on screen

MOV AH, 0x0E
MOV BH, 0x00
MOV BL, 0x07

INT 0x10
RET
;===============================================================

;===============================================================
PrintString: ;Procedure to print string on screen

MOV AL , [SI]
CALL PrintCharacter
NextChar:
INC SI
MOV AL , [SI]
CMP AL , 0
JZ exit_function
CALL PrintCharacter
JMP NextChar
exit_function:
RET
;===============================================================

;===============================================================

times (495) - ($ - $$) db 0
db 0
dw 0xAA52
dd 0xAA53
dq 0xAA54
dw 0xAA55 ;End of Boot-loader

;===
```

It doesn't output the first message.How can I correct it?.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For defining the strings, you should be using `db` (or possibly `dw`) instead of `dd`/`dq`.

Oh, and you should have a jump to your actual code *before* the string data, or the CPU will think the strings are code that should be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't read any further than this (comments elided):

```
[ORG 0x7C00]

MSG1 dd '1. Boot Loader starts ', 0
```

This means the first few bytes of your code isn't code at all, but rather an ASCII string.  You want something like this:

```
[ORG 0x7C00]

jmp start

; comments blah blah blah
MSG1 db '1. Boot Loader starts ', 0
; ... etc ...

start:

; instructons start here.

mov si, MSG1
; ...
```

Comment: Might also want to assure that `ds` is zero. It "might" be, when BIOS turns control over to our bootloader, but it is not assured!